# Could not obtain JDBC connection Oracle-xe with testcontainers - SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, oracle-xe

I am working on integrating testconatiners with oracle-xe with spring boot application. Container is starting but not able to connect to DB
Error- `Caused by: org.testcontainers.exception.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain JDBC connection`
I dont have any clue why its not able to connect to DB. Thanks in advance for the help :-)

gradle-

```
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:oracle-xe:1.15.3"
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.3"
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.3"
```

OracleTestContainer.java

```
public class OracleTestContainer extends OracleContainer {


    public static final String DB_CONNECTION_URL = "DB_URL";
    public static final String DB_USERNAME = "DB_USERNAME";
    public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "DB_PASSWORD";
    private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "gvenzl/oracle-xe";
    private static OracleTestContainer container;

    private OracleTestContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static OracleTestContainer getInstance(String initScriptPath) {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new OracleTestContainer();
            container.withInitScript(initScriptPath);
            container.start();
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty(DB_CONNECTION_URL, container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty(DB_USERNAME, container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty(DB_PASSWORD, container.getPassword());
    }
}
```

ApplicantTestConfig.java

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.test"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.abc.test")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.test1.entity","com.abc.test1.entity" })
    public class ApplicantTestConfig {
    
    }
```

AbstarctTest.java

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicantTestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    public static final String INIT_SCRIPT = "test-container-init.sql";

    public static final  OracleContainer oracle = OracleTestContainer.getInstance(INIT_SCRIPT);

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        if (!oracle.isCreated()) {
            oracle.start();
        }
    }

}
```

test class

```
@SpringJUnitConfig({ JobConfiguration.class})
class ValidateLinksJobTest extends AbstractTest {
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver:
      class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:oracle-xe:///db?TC_INITSCRIPT=classpath:test-container-init.sql
    username: limsreport
    password: pwd
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 2
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Environment Variables =

```
TESTCONTAINERS_CHECKS_DISABLE=TRUE;DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375;ORACLE_PASSWORD=oraclexe
```

Logs

```
19:19:33.645 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:19:33.653 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:19:33.654 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:19:33.662 [Test worker] INFO docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Waiting for database **connection to become available at jdbc:oracle:thin:system/oracle@localhost:32782:xe using query 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'**
19:19:33.663 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:19:33.663 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:19:33.756 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:19:33.756 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
**19:19:34.281 [Test worker] DEBUG docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Failure when trying test query
java.sql.SQLException: Could not create new connection**
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:228)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:147)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:440)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:325)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:323)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.OracleTestContainer.start(OracleTestContainer.java:33)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.OracleTestContainer.getInstance(OracleTestContainer.java:26)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.AbstractTest.<clinit>(AbstractTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:550)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConstructorInvocation.proceed(ConstructorInvocation.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    19:23:33.432 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:23:33.432 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:23:33.541 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:23:33.541 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:23:33.649 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:23:33.649 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:23:33.771 [Test worker] INFO docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:system/oracle@localhost:32782:xe)
19:23:33.771 [Test worker] INFO docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Container gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest started in PT4M0.827S
19:23:33.777 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils - Executing database script from test-container-init.sql
19:23:33.781 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d,false
19:23:33.781 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/c3582e9b60b97e518341f21cc27030b954533107df4cbfbef939cc4c1632776d/json], queryParams={}}
19:23:33.787 [Test worker] ERROR org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate - Could not obtain JDBC connection
19:23:33.788 [Test worker] ERROR docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Could not start container
**org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script from resource [--------- SCHEMA -------------------------------------------**
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_TABLE;
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:323)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.OracleTestContainer.start(OracleTestContainer.java:33)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.OracleTestContainer.getInstance(OracleTestContainer.java:26)
    at com.lexi.lims.configuration.AbstractTest.<clinit>(AbstractTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:550)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConstructorInvocation.proceed(ConstructorInvocation.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.exception.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain JDBC connection
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:34)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.delegate.AbstractDatabaseDelegate.getConnection(AbstractDatabaseDelegate.java:23)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.execute(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:42)
    at org.testcontainers.delegate.AbstractDatabaseDelegate.execute(AbstractDatabaseDelegate.java:34)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:362)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not create new connection**
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:228)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:31)
    ... 101 common frames omitted
19:23:33.817 [Test worker] ERROR docker[gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest] - Log output from the failed container:
CONTAINER: starting up...
Oracle Database SYS and SYSTEM passwords have to be specified at first database startup.
Please specify a password either via the $ORACLE_PASSWORD variable, e.g. '-e ORACLE_PASSWORD=<password>'
or set the $ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD environment variable to any value, e.g. '-e ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD=yes'.
```